# can't drag window to workspace

Tags: workspaces

I'm using Ubuntu 17.10 and this is my first time using Linux.

I'm trying to drag a window into another workspace but it's not working. I'm following the instructions here: https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/shell-workspaces-movewindow.html

Once I'm inside the activity page,

- If I hover over the windows (entire left 3/4 of the screen), the workspace selector on the right is closed.
- If I hover over the right edge of the screen, the workspace selector slides out and I can see all of my workspaces.
- When I try to drag a window from the left to the workspace selector on the right, the workspace selector will close and won't let me drop a window into a specific workspace. In other words, steps 3 & 4 from the link doesn't work when I'm dragging a window.

Is this normal behavior? If so, how do I manually drag and drop a window to a workspace?

Answer (score 0):

I like `Workspaces to Dock` GNOME Shell extension.

Drag the mouse pointer to the right side of the screen. A dock will slide out. In the dock, just drag the desired window from one workspace to another.

Find it at https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/427/workspaces-to-dock/